# in .pipe() when delay(2000) is used, .subscribe is not getting triggered. (Angular Rxjs)

Tags: angular, angular-observable

I have an observable in which .pipe() is being used, I am setting a flag true in tap() and giving delay(2000) in pipe() then I have given .subscribe() which is not getting triggered

I have tried removing the delay, it works. Both the consoles in tap and subscribe is getting displayed however when delay() is given in pipe it doesn't. I tried giving .debounceTime as well which didn't help.

```
this.sp
  .myService(data)
  .pipe(
    tap(data => {
      console.log(data, "in tap");
    }),
    delay(2000)
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log("should trigger after 2000ms");
  });
```

Expected output "data in tap";
"should trigger after 2000ms"

Comment: "This code doesn't work" should be sided with a [mcve]. Please provide one on https://stackblitz.com/ Also, as a newcomer, consider reading [ask] before posting a question.

Comment: Could not replicate; in the console on https://rxjs.dev/, `rxjs.of("data").pipe(rxjs.operators.tap(data => console.log(data, "in data")), rxjs.operators.delay(2000)).subscribe(data => console.log(data, "in subscribe"))` worked as expected.

Comment: In https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-no1j32?file=src/app/app.component.ts works too, check the version of Rxjs,